# Is there a way to execute user functions automatically in Python using loops?

Tags: python, loops, sas

I've been trying to implement the following SAS code in Python, and while I haven't had any problems translating the code that converts the table into what I require, I have been executing the function manually by changing the parameters each time.

SAS Code:

```
%LET SOURCEDATA =
PRACTICE.RURAL_SHOPS;

%MACRO DATAPROCESSOR(YEAR =, QUARTER =, COL1 =, COL2 =, KEYCOL =);
    PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE RURALSHOP&YEAR&QUARTER AS
        SELECT 
            &KEYCOL,
            SUM(SHOPNO) AS SHOPNO&YEAR&QUARTER,
            SUM(OPSHOP) AS OPSHOP&YEAR&QUARTER,
            SUM(CLSHOP) AS CLSHOP&YEAR&QUARTER
        FROM
            &SOURCEDATA
        WHERE 
            &COL1 = &YEAR AND &COL2 = &QUARTER
        GROUP BY 
            &KEYCOL;
    QUIT;
%MEND DATAPROCESSOR;

%MACRO REPEAT;
    %DO I = 2014% TO 2019;
    %DO J = 1% TO 4;
    %DATAPROCESSOR(YEAR = &I, QUARTER = &J, COL1 = YEAR, COL2 = QUARTER, KEYCOL = AREACODE);
    %END;
    %END;
%MEND;

%REPEAT;
```

Is there a way to implement the part that automatically executes the function using a loop in Python? Here's what I've currently got in Python:

```
sample_data = pd.DataFrame({"YEAR" : [2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019], \
                         "QUARTER" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], \
                         "AREACODE" : [100001, 100001, 100002, 100002, 100003, 100003, 100004, 100004, 100005, 100005, 100006, 100006], \
                         "SHOPNO" : [10, 12, 31, 5, 6, 9, 1, 3, 4, 0, 10, 2], \
                         "OPSHOP" : [1, 1, 3, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1], \
                         "CLSHOP" : [0, 0, 5, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 0]})   
    
def createmaster(df, keycol, keycol1, keycol2, year, quarter):
        df = df[(df["{}".format(keycol1)] == year) & (df["{}".format(keycol2)] == quarter)].groupby("{}".format(keycol)).sum()
        df = df.rename(columns = {"SHOPNO" : "SHOPNO{}{}".format(year, quarter), 
                                  "OPSHOP" : "OPSHOPNO{}{}".format(year, quarter), 
                                  "CLSHOP" : "CLSHOP{}{}".format(year, quarter)})
        df = df.drop(columns = ["YEAR", "QUARTER"])
        return df
```

Comment: Python's equivalent to the `DO` loops is `for … in range(…):`, but I'm not convinced you are on the right track. Changing the column names to contain the year, really? Why?

Comment: The dataset that I'm working with contains data regarding the number of shops in areas designated by the index column ("AREACODE"). What I want to do here is to separate the total number of shops ("SHOPNO"), the total number of new shops ("OPSHOP") and the total number of closed shops ("CLSHOP") for each quarter into individual columns. Once the individual datasets are created I plan on merging them into a mastertable that will then be used to create derived variables that indicate annual growth rates for each area.

Comment: I wouldn't do it the way you did it in SAS, so it's a bit hard to say how you should do this in Python, as they both have basically the same solutions here.  Why do you want multiple columns?  You can get your derived variables without a bunch of passes through the data like this.  Is the goal here just the final thing - the annual growth rates - or is the table with columns for each of the year/quarter combos a requirement in itself?

Answer (score 0):

In SAS, what you should have done here is run `PROC MEANS` with a `CLASS` statement, which would generate what you asked for with nearly no code.

This does it with one pass through the data, then two passes through the summarized data, and nothing complex: just a summary, a quick pass through to fix the names for the output, and then a transpose.  I write the SAS here just to show how the Python should also be.  This uses `sashelp.prdsale` which is a fairly similarly structured dataset to yours.

```
proc means data=sashelp.prdsale nway;
  class country region year quarter;
  var actual predict;
  output out=prd_means sum(actual)= sum(predict)=;
run;

data prd_names;
  set prd_means;
  name = catx('_','actual',year,quarter);
  value = actual;
  output;
  name = catx('_','predict',year,quarter);
  value = predict;
  output;
  keep name value country region;
run;

proc transpose data=prd_names out=prd_vars;
  by country region;
  var value;
  id name;
run;
```

So, in Python let's do it the same way - get an aggregate summary, then reshape it as you want.  I'm going to use `saspy` to grab the `prdsale` dataset; you can use this code on your sample dataset just the same.

```
import pandas as pd

#Everything from here to ...
import saspy
sas = saspy.SASsession(cfgname='winiomIWA')
prdsale = sas.sasdata2dataframe(table='prdsale',libref='sashelp')
#...here is just getting the dataframe set up - use your own dataframe here.

sums = prdsale.groupby(['COUNTRY','REGION','YEAR','QUARTER']).agg ('sum').unstack(['YEAR','QUARTER'])
print(sums)
```

Really all you need is that next to last line (and the import): `.groupby([... var list to summarize by, inc. year and quarter at the end]).agg('sum').unstack(['YEAR','QUARTER'])`.

Here, `groupby` tells it how to group the data when calculating the sums, `agg` says to sum the variables, and `unstack` says to reshape it afterwards for those two variables (meaning turn rows into columns for those variables).

I also suspect `pivot_table()` would do just as well...

```
pv = prdsale.pivot_table(index=['COUNTRY','REGION'],columns=['YEAR','QUARTER'],
                         values=['ACTUAL','PREDICT'],aggfunc='sum')
```

Both return basically the same thing, I don't know which is faster if that matters here. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981922/aggregate-transpose-and-pull-in-value-in-pandas-dataframe) for another example of this (though there's not really any aggregation going on there).